# Excel nested hierarchy from two lists

Tags: excel, list, pivot

I have two lists: `breakfast, lunch, dinner, snack` and `plan, prep, cook, serve, clean`. I need to create a table in excel that will look like this:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| breakfast |  |  |
|  | plan |  |
|  | prep |  |
|  | cook |  |
|  | serve |  |
| lunch |  |  |
|  | plan |  |
|  | prep |  |
|  | cook |  |
|  | serve |  |
| dinner |  |  |
|  | plan |  |
|  | prep |  |
|  | cook |  |
|  | serve |  |
| snack |  |  |
|  | plan |  |
|  | prep |  |
|  | cook |  |
|  | serve |  |

Each item from List#2 will appear under each item from List#1.
The values in List#1 and List#2 will be updated, could be managed in separate Sheet, but this output table should update those values. Both list could have large number of items hence I am hoping to create a dynamic table.

I've tried Pivot Table, but TBH not my forte and will appreciate some help :)

Thank yoU!

Comment: You'll probably need to use VBA or Power Query.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Private Const DATA_ROW As Integer = 1
' Column "A"
Private Const DATA_COLUMN_LIST1 As Integer = 1
'Column "B"
Private Const DATA_COLUMN_LIST2 As Integer = 2

Private Const NLIST1 As Integer = 4
Private Const NLIST2 As Integer = 5

Public List1() As String
Public List2() As String

Public Sub X()
Dim I As Integer
Dim J As Integer
Dim Z As Integer

  ReDim List1(NLIST1)
  List1(1) = "breakfast"
  List1(2) = "lunch"
  List1(3) = "dinner"
  List1(4) = "snack"
  
  ReDim List2(NLIST2)
  List2(1) = "plan"
  List2(2) = "prep"
  List2(3) = "cook"
  List2(4) = "serve"
  List2(5) = "clean"
  
  Z = DATA_ROW
  For I = 1 To NLIST1
     ActiveSheet.Cells(Z, DATA_COLUMN_LIST1).Value = List1(I)
     Z = Z + 1
     For J = 1 To NLIST2
        ActiveSheet.Cells(Z, DATA_COLUMN_LIST2).Value = List2(J)
        Z = Z + 1
     Next
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I suppose this is not possible on Excel for Mac :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Power Query solution.

It relies on you having two named ranges in your workbook (with workbook scope).
Of course, you could use table names instead with some modification of the m-code.

- Start the PQ Editor by creating a Blank Query.
- Paste the code below into the Advanced Editor
- Read the comments and go through the Applied Steps to better understand the algorithm.
- It should be dynamic and adapt to changes in the number of items in List1 and List2

**M Code**

```
let

//List1 and List2 should be named ranges with Workbook scope
//With slight rewriting, they could also be TABLES (and should be separate tables
    Source1 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="List1"]}[Content],
    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="List2"]}[Content],
    
    //extract list2
    //   add a null for the first entry
    //   repeat the list by the number of entries in list1
    //   Turn into a table
    list2 = Table.FromList(List.Repeat({null} & Source2[Column1],List.Count(Source1[Column1])),Splitter.SplitByNothing(),{"B"}),

    //Add index column for joining with list1
    list2IDX = Table.AddIndexColumn(list2,"IDX",0,1,Int64.Type),
    
    //extract list1
    //  for each item in list1, add one null item for each item in list2
    list1 = Table.FromList(
        List.Accumulate(
            Source1[Column1],
            {},
            (state, current) =>
                List.Combine({state, {current}, List.Repeat({null},Table.RowCount(Source2))})),
        Splitter.SplitByNothing(),{"A"}),

    //Add index column for joining with list2
    list1IDX= Table.AddIndexColumn(list1,"IDX",0,1,Int64.Type),

    //join the two tables and remove the index column
    tbl = Table.Join(list1IDX,"IDX",list2IDX,"IDX"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(tbl,{"IDX"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

**Lists**
[image]

**Results**
[image]

Comment: I suppose this is not possible on Excel for Mac :(

Comment: @AntonTeterine That's why it's important to let us know your Excel version these days.  But if you have Office 365 on the Mac, then it is possible.  But other Mac versions do not include Power Query.